# Haskell let-in Construct

Tags: haskell

Why is the result of these two functions not equivalent?

```
mnr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]  :: [Int]
name = "Max Mustermann" :: String

t1 = ("p1",(length.take 2)mnr, (take 2.(let no name = name;in no))"No");
{- ("p1",2,"No") -}

t1' = ("p1",(length.take 2)mnr, (take 2.(let no n = name;in no))"No");
{- ("p1",2,"Ma") -}
```

The only difference in these functions is the name of the variable in let.

Best regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you turn on `-Wall`, you will see a warning in `t1` that `name` shadows the existing binding for `name`:

```
let no name = name
       ^^^^--- this one
```

shadows

```
name = "Max Mustermann" :: String
```

So the `name` inside the function is the argument, making the function the same as `id`, while in `t2` the `name`:

```
let no n = name
```

is the one defined at top-level.

Comment: Yet another reason to always use `-Wall`!